# Ubuntu 17.10 Dual boot - external drive won't start, black screen on fresh installation

Tags: dual-boot, 17.10, boot-repair

I am aware of all the posts around Ubuntu black screens. But before you mark this as a duplicate, please consider my current working environment:

- Computer = Dell XPS 9350
- Ubuntu 17.10 installed on external drive (Seagate Expansion) running legacy boot mode.
- Internal drive running Windows in UEFI Boot mode
  -

I have tried [Ubuntu Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) without success. I gets stuck at " Loading initial ramdisk...".

**Workaround**

If I plug in a live CD/DVD USB stick then boot, External drive loads Ubuntu just fine with all my programs / files intact.

This makes me feel that perhaps the boot partition is corrupt in some way but boot repair didn't help me.

I have attached the Boot repair logs here: 
https://pastebin.com/zuff0gLz

And results here:
https://pastebin.com/eUrV9ZLM

Thank you for the time to read my post, let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: I do not see any obvious problem with boot repair but I do not believe it is a good idea to mix and match UEFI and "legacy" boot. You would then need to enable uefi to boot windows and disable it to boot ubuntu and sometimes disabling uefi will corrupt windows. I would install ubuntu with uefi enabled rather than legacy boot.

Comment: Wouldn't this affect windows boot if I did this? From the sources I've been reading online it says you should disable UEFI + fast/secure boot for dual booting Ubuntu.

Comment: Disable fast boot. Disable secure boot is optional (should work with secure boot enabled) . You should leave UEFI enabled .